# change multiple column values to other column if column is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This seems silly but i have a dataframe of the format like:

```
year      2016     2017     2018     2019      2020     2021
week                                                        
1      88698.0  75212.0  59224.0  63624.0   82784.0  66048.0
2      86725.0  68024.0  55546.0  62046.0   81804.0  59818.0
3      80426.0  64087.0  51355.0  58091.0   80581.0  57610.0
4      74888.0  58824.0  50126.0  54316.0   77236.0  56053.0
5      71659.0  52226.0  45962.0  51765.0   77976.0  51545.0
6      67431.0  50006.0  42438.0  52033.0   71822.0  48649.0
7      63613.0  46975.0  39840.0  48140.0   68726.0  43491.0
8      60174.0  46794.0  39370.0  46787.0   68132.0  41246.0
9      59495.0  42855.0  37844.0  44772.0   64557.0  41199.0
10     59487.0  42021.0  35470.0  43806.0   61529.0  41029.0
11     59118.0  41884.0  33731.0  44905.0   61379.0  41269.0
12     59542.0  40281.0  32671.0  45564.0   59424.0      NaN
13     61170.0  39117.0  33416.0  46906.0   59134.0      NaN
14     63785.0  37985.0  33039.0  48134.0   59027.0      NaN
15     65038.0  37120.0  33260.0  50554.0   56780.0      NaN
16     67441.0  36968.0  32937.0  51797.0   57442.0      NaN
17     68188.0  36702.0  33599.0  53271.0   56835.0      NaN
18     69303.0  38486.0  35737.0  54197.0   59376.0      NaN
19     70224.0  39051.0  37453.0  57114.0   61625.0      NaN
```

What i would like to do is change the value in all columns to match the value in 2021 if and only if the value in 2021 is not NaN. if it is NaN I would like the other columns to retain their values. I have tried iterrows but doing so turns it into a 1D array so I am not sure where I am erring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us check

```
df = df.mask(df['2021'].notna(),df['2021'],axis=0)
```

Comment: thank you, very helpful! i have a related question i have posted but i understand if that's not allowed to ask here

Answer (score 0):

Not tested for your case, but you can select the data you want and change their values by condition statements on other columns

df['2020'][ (df['2021'] != NaN) ] = df['2021'][ (df['2021'] != NaN) ]

You might have to fine-tune this, so make sure to duplicate your dataframe just in case, but this theoretically would select the row numbers that are not nan in 2021 for both cases so only those rows in 2020 are being updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use mask for the task:

```
m = ~df["2021"].isna()

df.loc[:, "2016":] = df.loc[:, "2016":].apply(
    lambda x: np.where(m, df["2021"], x)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    year     2016     2017     2018     2019     2020     2021
0      1  66048.0  66048.0  66048.0  66048.0  66048.0  66048.0
1      2  59818.0  59818.0  59818.0  59818.0  59818.0  59818.0
2      3  57610.0  57610.0  57610.0  57610.0  57610.0  57610.0
3      4  56053.0  56053.0  56053.0  56053.0  56053.0  56053.0
4      5  51545.0  51545.0  51545.0  51545.0  51545.0  51545.0
5      6  48649.0  48649.0  48649.0  48649.0  48649.0  48649.0
6      7  43491.0  43491.0  43491.0  43491.0  43491.0  43491.0
7      8  41246.0  41246.0  41246.0  41246.0  41246.0  41246.0
8      9  41199.0  41199.0  41199.0  41199.0  41199.0  41199.0
9     10  41029.0  41029.0  41029.0  41029.0  41029.0  41029.0
10    11  41269.0  41269.0  41269.0  41269.0  41269.0  41269.0
11    12  59542.0  40281.0  32671.0  45564.0  59424.0      NaN
12    13  61170.0  39117.0  33416.0  46906.0  59134.0      NaN
13    14  63785.0  37985.0  33039.0  48134.0  59027.0      NaN
14    15  65038.0  37120.0  33260.0  50554.0  56780.0      NaN
15    16  67441.0  36968.0  32937.0  51797.0  57442.0      NaN
16    17  68188.0  36702.0  33599.0  53271.0  56835.0      NaN
17    18  69303.0  38486.0  35737.0  54197.0  59376.0      NaN
18    19  70224.0  39051.0  37453.0  57114.0  61625.0      NaN
```